# How to pass phone number to phone application from scope

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, scopes, javascript

I'd like to be able to pass a phone number to the phone application from within a preview of a scope.

- Is that possible?
- Is it done with action widgets?
- Is there an example
  of this somewhere in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do it by specifying a tel: URI in a actions preview widget's url, e.g.:

```
var actions_widget = new scopes.lib.PreviewWidget("actionsId", "actions");
actions_widget.add_attribute_value(
  "actions",
  [
    {
      "id": "call",
      "label": "Call",
      "uri": "tel:+555555555"
    }
  ]
);
```

in the run() callback as you create a PreviewQuery

Comment: I've added your example.  The widget is showing up, but empty as an orange rectangle.  It also doesn't trigger the phone.